# C# best practice for custom global packages/helper methods etc.?

Tags: c#

I'm coming to C# from Python & JS and am enjoying it thoroughly so far. One of the quirks however is that it seems a lot of steps need to be taken to do some simple things. For instance if I have a 2D array and want to simply print out a 2D matrix to the console, this will require more code rather than calling a simple method like in Python. This is because printing the array will print the object type rather than its inner values. I've read one book so far and already know about method overriding, such as overriding .ToString() to do this, and know how to do this, so my question is more **"what is the best practice to create and use your own global methods to do common tasks?"** Or do any libraries exist that may already include many simple featurs like this?

What I'm looking to do is one of two things, and I'm curious which might be considered "better practice" -

1) **Array** is an object that has a lot of useful methods for manipulating arrays, but I'd like it if there was a method such as Array.PrintArray(arr) which would print the array and any inner arrays to the console. Since it seems there's no native method to do this, I'd like to write my own Array.PrintArray(arr) and make it available **globally to all projects**. Doing this seems like I'd need to extend the native Array object, and use this extension globally. I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's even a good idea to do that.

2) Alternatively if the above isn't good practice, I'd like to write my own helper object, lets call it "HelperSelf" with a list of my own methods, and make this helper object available globally to all projects. Eg, I could define a method **HelperSelf.PrintArray** so that I could type **HelperSelf.PrintArray(arr)** in any project in C# to print that array to the console in a way I define it.

So my question is twofold -

1) What is the best way to centrally define a way to do something via my own "helper" methods that I code so that the entire C# namespace has access to these helper methods?

2) Is doing something like this considered "best practice" or useful in C#? Does anyone else do something like this to print n-dimensional arrays to the console without having to manually write longer lines of code every time they wish to do so? Or is doing something like this considered highly unusual and it's better we just stick to writing multiple lines of code each time?

The printing n-dimensional array to console is an example of just one thing I want to do. In reality I'd like to code probably tens, or even 100+ of my own "helper" functions which I think would make things in C# much simpler coming from a Python background.

PS: The reason I want to use C# instead of Python is for projects that are better suited for C#, such as game development, systems operations, large scale projects where I find typing to be an incredibly useful feature, etc.

Comment: Have a look at https://nuget.org

Comment: Learning C# idioms takes time and practice, like learning how to write pythonic code did. Before putting packages that only you are likely to use on nuget.org, try hosting your own NuGet server (new .NET web application (not core, not yet, I don't believe), install the [NuGet Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/) package, and deploy) where you can try things out and erase from the record whatever doesn't work or is no longer useful. Then configure that source either in the IDE Options or in per-project `nuget.config` files.

Comment: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354) There is no "best way" that is appropriate in all possible circumstances. If you want achieve concrete, technical goals, ask for those, or the question risks being closed for being opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perhaps one of the reasons why languages like php, python etc get a bad rap, because they might have lots of these "semi useless" things built in. I don't personally regard "printing a 2d array to the console" as a particularly useful thing for the .net framework to contain because I don't recall, in the last 10 years, printing to the console in anything more than a scrappy test app of dotnetfiddle.com - none of the enterprise systems I work on write anything to the console though they can be configured to I suppose; they use NLog and custom loggers to write to Azure table storage etc but I could drop a console connector in there if I wanted to. Tend to just look up the logging output in Azure- we have a visualisation tool for it even

#### 1)

make a static method or a static class that has your helpers, possibly in another project so you can import it and reference it. If you make the most amazing set of console drawing classes you can even package it as a NuGet offering and make it available to the world but on the simple level putting it in a NuGet serve (and you can easily host your own if your library isn't likely to find widespread use) means it's a few clicks to get it into your next project. Here's a simple one liner to flatten a 2d array Into a csv string for printing to the console, for example:

```
public static PrintArray(object [][] a){

  var s = string.Join("\r\n", a.Select(inner => string.Join(",", inner));
  Console.WriteLine(s);

}
```

Once this is written inside your helper class you can import the helper namespace to anywhere in your project and call it. You could even turn it into an extension method so that all arrays gain then ability to just say `somearray.PrintArray` rather than `PrintHelper.PrintArray(x)` though it wouldn't give expected results on arrays of other dimensions than 2

#### 2)

whether it's unusual largely depend on your context. As noted for me it would be highly unusual to ever touch the console but if one day I went somewhere where there was some legacy cgi app that they couldn't replace with something better then it might well be that every project I wrote would have to output csv data in a very particular format to the console so the other app could consume it. It's not easy to say an answer that addresses this in all possible contexts but I do truly appreciate that Microsoft strive to keep the framework relatively bloat free, and resist adding methods that to a large extent would only be of interest to a narrow section of the population, instead preferring to focus on providing ways to make very generically capable methods to let you build the specific you want.

LINQ is one great example of this and a testament to its success in this regard is that once people discover it they tend to view it as a hammer and every problem is a nail; it ends up getting abused for all sorts of things, sometimes inappropriately - as generic, adaptable solutions often do. There is no question that it makes your developer life easier by cutting down the number of loops you have to write though. Once upon a time finding the max int in an array or calculating whether an array had a person whose last name was smith looked like:

```
int m = int.MinValue;
foreach(int x in array)
  if(x>m)
    x=m;

bool found = false;
foreach(var p in personarray)
  if(p.LastName == "Smith"){
    found = true;
    break;
  }
```

Now it's:

```
intarray.Max();

personarray.Any(p=>p.LastName == "Smith");
```

I do look at c# as more like a box full of Lego bricks where you build your own castles, where other languages have a lot of prebuilt castles floating around in with all the individual bricks. LINQ is one example of a fabulous prebuilt castle that does all sorts of wonderful things, but the way it's been able to be worked into the framework means it's still super generic and can be imported to create a set of extensions across all your arrays, lists, and other data containers, and in and of itself it doesn't do anything particular other than visit every element of a sequence and call a bit of code you provide so you're still tasked with making it specifically useful by crafting that code

---

The suggestion to look at NuGet.org is a good one; everyone has written everything. Your desire to write hundreds of helper classes may well have already been filled. I tend to find when it comes down to the brass tacks of actually doing my work, my job, I don't spend a lot of time writing helper classes because a lot of it is either on NuGet or turns out unnecessary because every project is different enough that curating a massive collection of helpers isn't actually helpful. One of the go to NuGet libraries that nearly every project I work on uses is Newtonsoft's JSON - interesting that it's an order of magnitude more downloaded than the rest of the top 100 (https://www.nuget.org/stats/packages) and that in itself is an indicator that the framework is fairly comprehensive in its ability to provide for most things you want to do without needing extra help. Coupled with the earlier points about it being relatively bloat free is probably an indicator of how well thought out it is in terms of "what do the majority of commercial applications need the framework to contain?"

I did also write a simple emailer helper some years ago that has found its way into many projects but by and large the company projects are bereft of suites of helpers created by our team, and have their own micro custom ones so don't spend a lot of time creating hundreds of them.. maybe let the work drive that one and only put in the library something that has been pasted into 3+ projects

Comment: Very useful information, particularly "I do look at c# as more like a box full of Lego bricks where you build your own castles". Looking at Python I was always a little perplexed by all the helper methods thinking "something so simple like that doesn't need to be in the core library" and can appreciate that C# keeps things more generic. I think I'll go ahead and write my own helper classes for the simple things I need now as a learning experience, and use established Nuget libraries as needed as I progress. Yours and Toan's answer, and madreflection's comment were all helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) and [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for that. For example, you can define Print extension method like this

```
public static class ArrayExtensions {
    public static void Print<T> (this IEnumerable<T> items) {
        foreach (var item in items) {
            Console.WriteLine (item);
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage like this

```
        var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        numbers.Print();
        var names = new string[] { "van", "ngan" };
        names.Print();
```

Comment: This is a good answer, except the original requirement was: "...which would print the array and any inner arrays"